# How to open inbuilt google calendar from any other application?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am developing an application in android and i want to use the inbulit phone calendar that android provides.
by any mean i want that when the user clicks on a button the google calendar appears?
plz help..
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents) over calendar intents and [how to view calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view).

Comment: sir dont wants to use google api, i just want to use the calendar of the phone

Comment: yes, use this uri: content://com.android.calendar/time/<ms_since_epoch> to open the calendar. Read the doc carefully.

Comment: sir as i am  bit new to android i m not able get that code properly plz help me make that code to understand and how to use it... plz thanks

Comment: It is explained in detail here:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view